# Mongoose 4.1 setters don't works with ObjectID fields

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have schemas like:

```
let fixClassID = (_this)=>{
 if(Object.keys(_this).length >= 2)
    if(_this.hasOwnProperty('_id'))
        _this = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_this['_id'])
 return _this
}

var student = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    class: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,  ref: 'class', set: fixClassID}
})

var school = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    students: [student],
})

school.pre('save', function(next) {

    //Here I got Error AND OLD OBJECT :(
})
```

In situation when frontend send me changed object BUT with populated class field like:

```
class: {_id: mongodID , name: "Chemestry"}
```

I need put on update only "_id" , and I need do it in setter not in controller. It's just example. I have more complicated object with nested arrays.

```
class: {_id: mongodID , name: "Chemestry"}
```

to

```
class: mongodID
```

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S. With "string" fields all works fine...

Comment: you need to convert it to ObjectId - `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_this['_id'])`

Comment: @Volodymyr already tried , nothing